# to flip the phrase around and keep the same gist?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

is that grammatically accepted to flip:

1.0 "of just enhancing the film they used a lot of technology"

as

2.0 "they used a lot of technology of just enhancing the film"

I believe in 2.0 example people would expect it to be:

"they used a lot of technology TO just enhancing the film"

but it is really meant to be "Of" to cause some sort of enphasis of film enhancing instead of creating the film from scratch.

I know it may not be the ebst way to make this enphasis, but is that grammatically accepted

Comment: The first one is Yoda-esque, and neither is idiomatic. *They used a lot of technology just to enhance the film*.

Comment: In both cases replace "of just enhancing" with "to just enhance", or at a pinch "for just enhancing". Both examples given are plain wrong to a native (British English) speaker. We would know what you meant simply because they can't mean anything else, but would mark you out as a non-native speaker. But, yes you can flip the sentences.

Comment: You should propose two alternatives *which are complete sentences*. Why not. That makes the options very clear to the reader.  I can't tell if those are fragments of a longer sentence, or they are supposed to be standalone.  A sentence starts with a capital letter, and ends with a period.   "of" looks wrong, it would be "to": "to enhance the film".  Prepositions in foreign languages is a difficult topic though.